# Testing that no methods (whatever the name) will be invoked in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Part of the test subject:

```php
class AddOptionsProviderArgumentPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if(!$container->hasDefinition('gremo_highcharts')) {
            return;
        }

        if(!$container->hasParameter('gremo_highcharts.options_provider')) {
            return;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to assert that:

- `hasDefinition()` call with parameter 'gremo_highcharts' will return `false`
- The method `process()` returns, that is no other method will be invoked

One solution would be asserting about the subsequent call to `hasParameter()`:

```php
public function testProcessWillReturnIfThereIsNoServiceDefinition()
{
    $container = $this->getMockedContainerBuilder();
    $pass = new AddOptionsProviderArgumentPass();

    $container->expects($this->once())
        ->method('hasDefinition')
        ->with($this->equalTo('gremo_highcharts'))
        ->will($this->returnValue(false));

    // Expects that hasParameter() is never invoked
    $container->expects($this->never())
        ->method('hasParameter');

    $pass->process($container);
}
```

But it doesn't seem an elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

To express `any method` you can use `$this->anything()`.

### Full example:

```
<?php

class fooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testNeverCallNothing() {
        $mock = $this->getMock('mockMe');
        $mock->expects($this->never())->method($this->anything());
        //$mock->bar();
    }
}

class mockMe {
    public function bar() {}
}
```

Outputs:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.10-4-ga0bccf3 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.50Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

### When commenting in the method call

```
$mock->bar();
```

it then outputs:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.10-4-ga0bccf3 by Sebastian Bergmann.

F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) fooTest::testNeverCallNothing
mockMe::bar() was not expected to be called.

.../tests/neverCallMe/fooTest.php:9

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Failures: 1.
```

---

## Allowing for only one method call but no calls to other methods

This looks a little ugly but also works

```
<?php

class fooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testNeverCallNothing() {
        $mock = $this->getMock('mockMe');
        $mock->expects($this->once())->method('foo');
        $mock->expects($this->never())->method(
            $this->logicalNot($this->matches('foo'))
        );
        $mock->foo();
        //$mock->bar();
    }


}

class mockMe {
    public function bar() {}
    public function foo() {}
}
```

Works. When commenting in the other method calls it fails like above.

If one wants to allow for multiple methods to be called it gets a little more verbose:

```
$this->logicalNot(
    $this->logicalOr(
        $this->matches('foo'),
        $this->matches('baz'),
        $this->matches('buz')
    )
)
```

Comment: Hey you really rock! Thanks for the great explanation, I'm going to lear and test further. Mind if I ask you to take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962206/fail-in-asserting-about-argument-types-in-phpunit

Answer (score 2):

Is it an exceptional case? If so, you could change the **first return** (why are you returning void anyway?) to **throwing a specific exception**. Then use PHPUnit to verify that that specific exception is actually caught.

Edit:
Also with Phake you could write something like this at the end of your test: (similar to calling ->never() with PHPUnit Mock Objects)

```
Phake::verify($container, Phake::times(0))->hasParameter();
```

This creates a distinction between stubbing method calls and verifying that methods (stubbed or not) have been called.

Comment: I'm returning void because no further processing should occur, and the returning value is never used. I can't throw any exception, is not an unexpected behavior...

Comment: Right I see. Then perhaps you could explain why the solution doesn't seem elegant to you? Like I said, you could try including Phake and separate the stubbing (hasDefinition) from the verifying (hasParameter).

Answer (score 1):

When testing such methods, try to see the big picture. Don't descend to the level of `if`s and `return`s, take it higher. By asserting that no other call was made after `return`, what You really test are the PHP's native statements, not the logic of Your method. It's like You don't trust the `return`s. Take my word for it, after `return` statement nothing is executed in that method :)

Instead, test the logic of Your method!

**What is the logic?**

Well, according to Your code, You have this class `AddOptionsProviderArgumentPass` and its `process` method. The `pocess` method takes a `ContainerBuilder` and processes it somehow. So, what You need to test is that the `process` method does its job well. Your `if`s in the method represent some constraints which need to be satisfied in order to successfully process the `ContainerBuilder`.

**How do You understand if the `process` was successful?**

By its return type.

**What if it doesn't return anything?**

Check for its side effects. Which are the things You do to the `ContainerBuilder`.

So, here is how I see it.

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function shouldNotProcessWithoutHighcharts()
{
    // Arrange
    $container = $this->buildContainer();
    $container->removeDefinition('gremo_highcharts');
    $pass = new AddOptionsProviderArgumentPass();

    // Act
    $pass->process($container);

    // Assert
    $this->assertFalse($container->hasWhatYouNeedItToHaveAfterProcessing())
}

/**
 * @test
 */
public function shouldNotProcessWithoutHighchartsOptionsProvider()
{
    // Arrange
    $container = $this->buildContainer();
    $container->getParameterBag()->remove('gremo_highcharts.options_provider');
    $pass = new AddOptionsProviderArgumentPass();

    // Act
    $pass->process($container);

    // Assert
    $this->assertFalse($container->hasWhatYouNeedItToHaveAfterProcessing())
}

private function buildContainer()
{
    $container = new ContainerBuilder();
    $container->setParameter('gremo_highcharts.options_provider');
    $container->setDefinition('gremo_highcharts');
    return $container;
}
```

**Last note**

Don't rely on the order of `if`s, it can change!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe creating Phake mocks and calling

```
Phake::verifyNoInteraction($mock);
```

is a good solution to this problem. Here's a link to the manual: https://phake.readthedocs.io/en/2.1/method-verification.html#verifying-no-interaction-with-a-mock-so-far .